# Minor typo on help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

On the [API Routes help page](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help), this:

> /users/{id}/favorites  Gets summary information for the questions that have been favorited a set of users.

should probably be:

> /users/{id}/favorites  Gets summary information for the questions that have been favorited ***by*** a set of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed